# Align text inside list item so it is not under element decoration

Tags: html, css

I need top-bottom borders for list items. The item's decoration needs to be customized and if element text is too long it should not be under the element decoration. I can't figure it out.

```css
div {
  width: 20%;
}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  padding: 0.1em 0.3em;
}

li span {
  position: relative;
  left: 1em;
}

li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: #800000;
  font-size: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 10px;
}

li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><span>foo</span></li>
    <li><span>bar</span></li>
    <li><span>very long sentence is here which should be nicely aligned</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vgec25Lw/26/

Comment: Can you share an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the position of your pseudo elements to absolute you get what you want:

```css
div {
  width: 20%;
}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  padding: 0.1em 0.3em;
}

li span {
  position: relative;
  left: 1em;
}

li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: #800000;
  font-size: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><span>foo</span></li>
    <li><span>bar</span></li>
    <li><span>very long sentence is here which should be nicely aligned</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Only problem: the text now overflows to the right.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  width: 20%;
}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  padding: 0.1em 0.3em;
  display: flex;
}

li span {
  position: relative;
  /* left: 1em; */
  width: fit-content;
}

li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: #800000;
  font-size: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 10px;
}

li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><span>foo</span></li>
    <li><span>bar</span></li>
    <li><span>very long sentence is here which should be nicely aligned</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should copy the original snippet down here and demonstrate your solution.

Comment: There's some odd difference in alignment between short lines and the long one

Comment: Then you should consider checking out @j08691's solution below. In his snippet, the text looks perfectly aligned. Or is it something else you're looking for?

Comment: My solution works just fine.

Answer (score -3):

You write that you want border top and bottom for the li elements but in your code I already see it and it is working fine.

About the alignment I guess you mean it to be one single line, in that case you can do this:

```css
div {
  width: 20%;
}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  padding: 0.1em 0.3em;
}

li span {
  position: relative;
  left: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: #800000;
  font-size: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 10px;
}

li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><span>foo</span></li>
    <li><span>bar</span></li>
    <li><span>very long sentence is here which should be nicely aligned</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```